# How to hide a Sidebar from other admins?

Tags: sidebar

Is there a function way that I can hide a sidebar from other admins? Meaning they can't see it so they can't edit its content but it is still there?

I'm wanting to place my copyright, developed by footer in a sidebar via a widget so it will allow me to create more footers like this for various layouts, but I don't want the client to have access to this sidebar.

I know I can do it through a conditional css function, but is there a function I can do to achieve this without just using css? Something Wordpress native?

Similar Example:

```
function Hide_Admin_Bar() {
if (!current_user_can('My_User_Name_Here') && !is_admin()) {
  show_admin_bar(false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I've used which is css based.

```
global $pagenow;
    if (in_array($pagenow, array('widgets.php'))) {

function Only_show_to_webmaster_user_things_by_css() {
    global $current_user;
    $username = $current_user->user_login;
    if ($username == 'Your_Username_Here') {
}
    else {
    ?>
<style>#Sidebar_ID_Here{display:none !important;}</style>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action('admin_head','Only_show_to_webmaster_things_by_css');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the [Adminimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/) plugin.  It lets you hide whole chunks of the admin screen and menus from certain user roles or even certain users.

If it doesn't do it directly (and I think it may not do this), then you could hook an action to [sidebar_admin_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/sidebar_admin_page). The easiest thing there (although there are surely more elegant and WP native ways), would be to do a conditional test for the user not being you, and if so write out CSS or javascript to hide the copyright sidebar.

Comment: Thanks Joel! I was able to achieve this some time ago with a conditional check and css. I didn't find any other way to do it yet. I also tried Adminimize back at that time and it didn't have the user based options but rather user role based options. 

I posted an example of my code above as the answer.